# Running NBehave plain text scenarious using TD.NET

Tags: c#, testing, bdd, nbehave

Is this possible?

Actually, any tips about running nbehave tests and integrating them with build server would be appreciated.

Maybe there's a good alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried behaveN?
http://code.google.com/p/behaven/

It uses nunit and therefore integrating it with build server should be easy(assuming that you are using nunit)

Comment: Looks worth checking out. Is it tied completely together with nUnit?

Comment: I can't pass string argument from text file scenario to my method. Ridiculous problem. ^^

Comment: can you publish the text file here? you don't have to use quotes btw.

Comment: Downloaded source. Played around with it and somehow got it working. I even don't know what i did wrong previously. So far so good. Pursuing `bdd+ui testing` combo.

Comment: I think i will stick with it. It's not tied with nUnit. It's not even tied with particular test runner. Seems that project is immature and there is lack of documentation but i don't need much from it and it's quite easy to understand source code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the nbehave examples, there's both a nant and a msbuild task.

Comment: Nah, it took me ages just to find out how to use debugger. I'm happy with BehaveN. Does what i need in elegant enough way.

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, it is possible with the current release. The release now includes .tdnet files that TestDriven finds to direct it find the correct assemblies and call your tests.